# Apex trigger to create contact from email-to-case if the email is not yet in our system

Tags: apex, trigger, case, email2case

I am trying to create an Apex trigger that will create a contact using the SuppliedEmail field of a case to avoid situations where we have a case that is not tied to an account (we will need all cases to be tied to accounts in order to implement SLAs via Entitlements). I found this answer: https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000009CSkIAM however I would really like to understand what is wrong with what I am doing as I will need to develop further features and it feels like I'm just not getting something very important about the whole system.

Here is my code:

```
trigger new_case_handling on Case (before insert) {
    System.debug('Entered execution procedure for new_case_handling trigger');
    for (Case receivedCase: Trigger.new) {
        Boolean contactCreated = false;
        if(receivedCase.AccountId == null && receivedCase.SuppliedEmail != null) {
            List<Account> unknownAccount = [SELECT Id FROM Account  WHERE Name = 'UNKNOWN ACCOUNT'];

            if(unknownAccount.size() != 0) {
                String fullEmail = String.valueOf(receivedCase.SuppliedEmail);
                String newUsername = 'NOTAVAILABLE';
                if(fullEmail.indexOf('@') != -1) {
                    newUsername = fullEmail.split('@').get(0);
                }
                Contact newContact = new Contact(
                    LastName = newUsername,
                    Email = receivedCase.SuppliedEmail,
                    AccountId = unknownAccount[0].Id);

                insert newContact;
                contactCreated = true;
                System.debug('Created contact ' + String.valueOf(receivedCase.SuppliedEmail) + ' on account ' + unknownAccount[0].Id );
            }
            else {
                System.debug('Unable to find UNKNOWN ACCOUNT to insert ' + String.valueOf(receivedCase.SuppliedEmail) + 'in' );
            }
            if(contactCreated) {
                List<Contact> createdContact = [SELECT Id FROM contact WHERE Email =:receivedCase.SuppliedEmail];
                if(createdContact.size() > 0){
                    receivedCase.contactId = createdContact[0].Id;
                    insert receivedCase;
                }
                else {
                    System.debug('Contact was created but query failed.');
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

When I set the trigger condition to `before update` and try to modify a case that came from an unregistered email address, it seems to work out totally fine -- it creates the contact on the UNKNOWN ACCOUNT account and assigns it to the ticket. However `before insert` doesn't seem to work at all, I am not able to see any logs in the Developer Console (although I am perhaps not looking for them properly), and the case does not end up being created at all(!). Can you guys please guide me toward what I am missing?

Comment: Hi @AndreyOsh, I think [this post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/280250/how-to-obtain-trigger-log-from-email2case) may help you in debugging this trigger. Keep in mind email2case runs under a specific context.

Comment: note that your trigger is not bulkified and will fail with too many soql on any data loader or other batch use case that inserts cases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In hindsight, this question is fairly dumb and I've figured out the problem. In a trigger that is set to `before insert` I was calling `insert` on the triggering item after having added the contact to the case. That seems like something that shouldn't work, and simply commenting out that line allows the code to function.